# ScrollView is not scrolling overflowed layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a scroll view containing one child layout(linear layout) and that child contains a relative layout and a linear layout. Relative layout and linear layout shares half-half screen. Linear layout has buttons added to it dynamically.

Now problem arises as scroll view does not scroll buttons while it scrolls relative layout and linear layout.

```
<ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>

  <RelativeLayout>       
  </RelativeLayout>

  <LinearLayout>
                          ->Dynamically adding buttons here
  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**I want those buttons scroll with scrollview**

For reference my xml code is :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/whitecolor"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

 <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     >

     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         >

<RelativeLayout 
   android:
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bluecolor"   
    />
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/stauslinearlayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/bluecolor"
    >
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/status"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textColorHint="#5222"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:ems="10"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/statusnumber"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/whitecolor"
    android:text="abcdfrg"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" 
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" 
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" 
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" 
    />
        <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" 
    />
        <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" 
    />            
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, If you want to divide screen in to same two sizes, you have to take another scrollView in bottom view, like below example...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/stauslinearlayout"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="status"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textColorHint="#5222" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="statusnumber" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:text="abcdfrg" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and if you don't want to take another scrollView, then you have to give wrap_contant to bottom linear-layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/stauslinearlayout"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="status"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textColorHint="#5222" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="statusnumber" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="abcdfrg" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

choice goes to your requirement.

if any problem yet, then plz ask... :-)

Comment: i can't use first method because i want both child layout to scroll with single scrollview. While second method is give same behaviour as my problem. However i have managed to do that by dynamically setting first child height to screen height/2 and then adding buttons to scrollview dynamically. Thanks a lot!